# How to structure Django project with external python packages interacting with the same database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, web-applications, sqlalchemy

I am developing a Django Rest Api for which I am targeting below structure:

```
django_project
│-- django_project
    │--__init.py__
    │-- asgi.py
    │-- setting.py
    │-- urls.py
    │-- wsgi.py
│-- app
    │-- migrations
    │-- __init.py__
    │-- admin.py
    │-- apps.py
    │-- models.py
    │-- tests.py
    │-- views.py
│-- manage.py
│-- media
│-- static
│-- templates
```

The thing is that I would like to include an external python package that I have developed for the data processing. This package uses slqalchemy for the db mapping so I am not sure how (and where) to fit it inside my django project since there will be duplicate models definition (with sqlachemy and Djando ORM).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many apps as you wish:

```
django_project
│-- django_project
    │--__init.py__
    │-- asgi.py
    │-- setting.py
    │-- urls.py
    │-- wsgi.py
│-- app_1
    │-- migrations
    │-- __init.py__
    │-- admin.py
    │-- apps.py
    │-- models.py
    │-- tests.py
    │-- views.py
│-- app_2
    │-- __init.py__
    │-- admin.py

 ...

│-- manage.py
│-- media
│-- static
│-- templates
```

Actually django app can be with or without django orm models.You don't have to register python package as app at settings to import and use it in other registered apps. Registration python package as django app is needed if we develop django orm models and use migrations, or have signals, or celery tasks, or urls.

Comment: Thanks @Valery Ramusik, although app2 is not strictly an app, it is a python package that interacts with the database (for data loading and processing). Can I still keep it inside the django_project directory?

Comment: Yes, you can import and use it